# ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended can't figure out why I am getting this error

Tags: sql, oracle

Could I please have some help in figuring out why this isn't working? I copy and paste the same query into SQL and it works just fine?

```
using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("SELECT o.load_number, p.part_number as sortpartnum, p.engineering_change as sortecl, ps.internal_part_#, ps.engineering_change, o.ship_date as custshipdate, o.ship_time as custshiptime, o.sched_ship_date as sortshipdate, o.sched_ship_time as sortshiptime, o.curr_quantity as sortcurqty, o.ship_quantity as sortshipqty, o.mr_number as sortmrnum, o.project_number as sortprojnum, o.transaction_set_id as sorttranssetid, o.id, p.id, o.rowid, o.ship_quantity, p.standard_pack_qty, o.load_number, o.row_version, o.po_number as sortponum, o.dock_code as sortdockcode, o.lot_number, o.batch_number, o.job_sequence, edi_cancellation, '', p.part_spec_id, 'N/A', '', '', o.sched_ship_date, -1 as sortload, '', '' FROM orders o, part_master p, part_specification ps WHERE o.load_number IS NULL AND o.part_id = p.id AND p.part_spec_id = ps.id AND" +

    "o.sched_ship_date <= SYSDATE + 30" +
    "UNION ALL" +
    "SELECT o.load_number, p.part_number, p.engineering_change, ps.internal_part_#, ps.engineering_change, o.ship_date, o.ship_time, o.sched_ship_date, o.sched_ship_time, o.curr_quantity, o.ship_quantity, o.mr_number, o.project_number, o.transaction_set_id, o.id, p.id, o.rowid, o.ship_quantity, p.standard_pack_qty, o.load_number, o.row_version, o.po_number, o.dock_code, o.lot_number, o.batch_number, o.job_sequence, edi_cancellation, '', p.part_spec_id, DECODE(l.inbond, 'Y', 'Yes', 'No'), '', '', o.sched_ship_date, o.load_number, '', DECODE(NVL(l.seq_quick_label, DECODE(NVL(sfx.seq_quick_label, 'N'), 'Y', 'Yes', 'No')), 'Y', 'Yes', 'No')  FROM loads l, orders o, part_master p, part_specification ps, ship_from_xref sfx WHERE o.load_number = l.load_number AND l.shipment_id IS NULL AND l.ship_from_xref_id = sfx.id AND p.id = o.part_id AND p.part_spec_id = ps.id" +
    "order by" +

        "sortload," +
        "sortpartnum," +
        "sortecl," +
        "sortshipdate," +
        "sortshiptime," +
        "sortcurqty," +
        "sortshipqty," +
        "sortmrnum," +
        "sortprojnum," +
        "sorttranssetid;", con))
```

just when I launch my netcore application it gives me this error

[image]

Comment: You're missing whitespace between the concatenated strings - look at the final string. e.g  it will have `30UNION`, but there are several places you do the same thing. It probably also should not have a semicolon at the end of the statement.

Comment: Also, depending on your library, it may not be necessary to append the semi-colon at the end. Some interfaces do that for you as a way to prevent SQL injection. If you correct the whitespace issues and still see the error, try removing the semi-colon.

Comment: when you join your string togther as you have posted it there are missing spaces.. you need to separate keywords/columns etc with whitespace.

Comment: About the semi-colon: it is NOT part of the SQL language standard. It is commonly used in command line interfaces like Oracle’s SQLPLUS to mark the end of a statement. But even there it is optional: you can enter a SQL statement without a terminating semi-colon then enter “/“ on a new line to execute it. So in your example, you must remove the trailing “;” (and make sure to add spaces as needed and already suggested)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple issues:

- Spacing between concatenation of the string - Spaces between two string which are used on both sides of the `+` must have spaces `[space]" + "[space]`
- In the last line, You are using the `;`, Just remove it.